# How to export local storage of 1 page and import in another?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is my local storage, I want to somehow export it from this page and import it to another. How can this be done? I wish to export it for backup purpose too.

[image]

Comment: Are both of the projects on the same domain?

Comment: yes same app, you can think of export and import option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains

Comment: but how can i export it as some file and import it later...in 1 software i saw this option, they used to export it as filename.anyextensionname and later import it

Comment: Probably they just saved the localStorage data in a JSON format, and then wrote an exporter / importer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [export Data in localStorage for later re-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335967/export-data-in-localstorage-for-later-re-import)

Comment: Also [How to write localStorage data to a text file in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693289/how-to-write-localstorage-data-to-a-text-file-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

To export:

```
 const export = JSON.stringify(localStorage);
```

To import:

```
 Object.assign(localStorage,JSON.parse(import));
```

How to get the exported string from the one page to the other is another question...

Comment: can you explain in more detail, will it export as a file and i need to upload that file for import ?

Comment: @usrr2828442 it exports a string. You can do with that whatever you like

Answer (score 1):

[StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension can easily help you with this. You can **Export/Copy** local storage items of one page and **Import** those in another page.

Along with Local Storage, it also easily manage Session Storage and Cookies.

[image]